# Java: how to check automatically which fields require a volatile modifier?

Tags: java, android-studio, volatile

`volatile` modifier is required when a variable is read/written by several concurrent Threads.

Are there tools that can detect missing `volatile` modifiers automatically, e.g. in Android Studio?

Algorithm:

```
for (Class c:allClasses) {
    for (Field f:allFields) {
        List<Method> allMethods = getCallHierarchy(field);
        
        for (Method m:allMethods) {
            List<Thread> threads = getCallingThreads();
            if (threads.size() > 1) {
                Log.w("Warning: field "+f+" is accessed by several threads.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code for testing the algorithm:

```
public class Foo {
    private int a; //accessed by only one Thread - ok
    private int b; //accessed by two Threads - show compiler warning

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        a = 10; //no race condition - ok
        
        b = 1;
        Thread th = new Thread(this::someMethod);
        th.start(); //update to field "b" might stay unnoticed for mainThread

        while(!isDone) {
            Thread.sleep(20); //wait for the other Thread to finish
        }

        b += 2;
        
        System.out.println(b); //3 or 6
    }
    
    private void someMethod() {
        b += 3;
        isDone = true;
    }

    private volatile boolean isDone = false;
}
```

Comment: That would seem to require complete flow-analysis to determine (a) which methods were called from which threads on which objects, and (b) whether any other synchronization was used.  And since threads are a runtime phenomenon, even then it can't be complete.

Comment: I mean, it's not required if you use other forms of locking, and it's not enough depending on what exact concurrency semantics you need, so such a flag might give users a very false sense of security.

Answer (score 6):

No, not possible.

> `volatile` modifier is required when a variable is read/written by several concurrent Threads.

This is flat out incorrect.

Any field that is accessed by multiple threads, at least one which is also writing, needs 'Happens-Before' guarding.

`volatile` is just *one* way to get it. `synchronized` is another. There are even more exotic ways.

Which code does this? That's.. impossible to tell. It's not possible to know at compile-time which line of code is likely to run under which thread. The way the thread model is set up, the halting problem being what it is, this is mathematically impossible to do.

This leaves precisely *one* route:

Have a Virtual Machine that does bookkeeping for *every* write to *every* non-volatile field in the entire system, marking down which lock(s) were active at the time, a rough timestamp, and a stacktrace.

That is an **unbelievable** amount of bookkeeping, even on a beefy phone with a ton of memory this is going to slow things down to a crawl. But, let's do it, and ask the developer or tester to painstakingly wait it out whilst they hit every feature on the phone.

After the system's been running a good long while find field accesses that time-wise appear to interleave and which have no shared active locks. Spit these accesses out: Voila, there's a list where the developer will need to check out what's going on and likely add some sort of locking mechanism. Could be 'Mark the field `volatile`', but far more likely you should be doing something else to ensure concurrent access is properly controlled; `volatile` is a bit of a loose cannon, most concurrency principles cannot be properly written with `volatile` fields.

I'm not aware of any such tool, but at least now you know specifically what to look for.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for Java TSAN, although that runs on OpenJDK.

Comment: The JVM would also have to record every read of every variable, to check whether it has been correctly guarded in respect to the preceding write. And it wouldn’t be enough to remember all locks active at the time of the variable access, as there are valid access schemes with in-between acquisition and releases. A parallel stream operation, for example, may make concurrent access to non-concurrent collections without holding any locks and still be correct. At the same time, as you mentioned, incorrect usage does not imply that you can fix it using `volatile`.

Answer (score 1):

You should find a tool that gives an inspection for necessity of volatile modifier, for example IntelliJ IDEA has a plugin:

[Mike's IDEA Extensions](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12690-mike-s-idea-extensions) has a (Java + Kotlin) inspection *Atomic can be replaced with volatile*

Then you can run a named inspection in IntelliJ for the whole project using Analyze | Inspect Code.